# how to fix uri undefined error when trying to send request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, axios

when I'm trying to call the request in front node, I'm getting error in my backend node " RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "undefined"" , it seems like backend node request is not getting the data form my frontend node request.
knowing that uploadLink already have a value and in my browser console the frontend request looks ok
[image]
my backend request code

```
const ThumbnailUpload = async (req, res) => {
  const { Uploadlink } = req.body;
  const { selectedFile } = req.body;
  const clientServerOptions = {
    uri: `${Uploadlink}`,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: selectedFile,
    }),
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': ' application/json',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
      Authorization: getVimeoAuthorization(),
    },
  };
  request(clientServerOptions, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
    } else {
      const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
      res.send(body);
    }
    console.log(Uploadlink);
  });
};
```

and my frontend code is

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      'selectedFile',
      new Blob([selectedFile], { type: 'image/jpg, image/png, or image/gif' }),
    );
    formData.append('uploadLink', uploadLink);

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpg, image/png, or image/gif',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
    };

    try {
      axios
        .post(`${backendPostPath}/thumbnail-upload`, formData, {
          headers,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          applyThumbnial();
          console.log(response);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

any advise ?

Comment: you need to assign some value to `uploadLink` on the frontend

Comment: the uploadLink already have a value I assigned it form  const [uploadLink, setUploadLink] = useState('');

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
const { Uploadlink } = req.body;
```

to:

```
const { uploadlink } = req.body;
```

make variable consistent throughout the code

**EDIT**

also, since you're uploading a file, you need to use upload middleware before request handler, and file will be within `req.file`:

```
route.post('/thumbnail-upload', upload.single('selectedFile'), ThumbnailUpload);

//... handler..
const selectedFile = req.file;
```

Comment: fixed variable issue , still getting same error.

Comment: @user18487023 on the server, add `console.log(req.body)`, is it empty?

Comment: @user18487023 your upload middleware is probably not configured, check the updated code

Comment: thanks a lot, file must go with request body as binary data base on api doc.

Comment: @user18487023 then you should convert it on the server, because with node you need to process it with `multer` first. also, you might check some libraries for vimeo uploading, if that's what you're doing, maybe upload it from the browser..