# how to use request response in another request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use the first express request and response data to the second request, the problem is that both requests need to have their own body data in case I want to use them in the frontend node, is there any efficient approach to solve this issue.
in my below requests code, I must use the uploadlink from the first request to the second request.

```
const ThumbnailUploadlink = async (req, res) => {
  const { videoId } = req.body;
  const clientServerOptions11 = {
    uri: `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/${videoId}/pictures`,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: videoId,
    }),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
      Authorization: getVimeoAuthorization(),
    },
  };
  request(clientServerOptions11, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
    } else {
      const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
      res.send(body);
      const uploadLink = body.link;

      console.log(uploadLink);
    }
  });
};

// uploadLink must take value from previous request
const ThumbnailUpload = async (req, res, uploadLink) => {
  const { selectedFile } = req.body;
  const clientServerOptions = {
    url: `${uploadLink}`,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name1: selectedFile,
    }),
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
      Authorization: getVimeoAuthorization(),
    },
  };
  request(clientServerOptions, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
      console.log(uploadLink);
    } else {
      const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
      res.send(body);
      console.log(uploadLink);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you add a little more context about how those 2 functions are must be called ?

Comment: So if I understood you correctly you want to call another controller function from anywhere in the app.

I would recommend using `axios` for this, call another controller API anywhere from your app doing this will call that function and you will have express request and response in that second controller function.

Comment: the both requests will be called in frontend node as I tried to pass the response data from frontend but it seems not working, this approach I tried to find a solution for it in below link, but didn't get any right way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663262/how-to-fix-uri-undefined-error-when-trying-to-send-request